# Apply Plugin CSS before Theme CSS WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a WordPress plugin in which there is template files and admin can access that template through shortcode. Problem I'm facing is Plugin CSS files loads after theme CSS files.

[image: See Attachment]

Please help me: How to Apply WordPress Plugin CSS files first then Theme CSS files.

I had wrote this code in plugin files @marko:

```
function olr_style_enqueue() {
wp_register_style('olr_bootstrap', plugins_url( 'css/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_style('olr_bootstrap');
wp_register_style('olr_bootstrap_extension', plugins_url( 'css/css/bootstrap.extension.css', __FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_style('olr_bootstrap_extension');
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'olr_style_enqueue');
```

How I can resolve my problem?

Comment: You have try to enter the code manually in the header.php? Usually all that WordPress writes it automatically puts it under what you write in the head tag

Comment: Wordpress writes it automatically

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is not a good idea.
At beginning Wordpress loads the theme and then the plugins.

First you can try if the css tag "!important" helps.

If not you can delete the css and put it your css and than put the deleted css right back.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'generate_remove_scripts' );
function generate_remove_scripts() 
{
    wp_dequeue_style( 'generate-child' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'generate_move_scripts', 999 );
function generate_move_scripts() 
{
    if ( is_child_theme() ) :
        wp_enqueue_style( 'generate-child', get_stylesheet_uri(), true, filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ), 'all' );
    endif;
}
```